# submitForm() not defined for myfaces.JSF_JS_MODE 'minimal-modern'

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2, myfaces, commandlink

I tried to set up a simple JSF 2.2 application using MyFaces 2.2.8.
Since MyFaces has some context parameters that I never used before, I tried to get familiar with those.

So I got to use `org.apache.myfaces.JSF_JS_MODE` for the first time and ran into problems with `h:commandLink`.
The commandLink is trying to call `myfaces.oam.submitForm()` which is not defined if I set the mode to `minimal-modern`.
If I set the mode to `minimal` or `normal` it works.

From reading some internet articles I assume this is a bug because submitForm is neither part of jsf-legacy.js nor jsf-i18n.js nor jsf-experimental.js and it apparently is needed by `h:commandLink`.
Also the source code comment of `org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.util.ResourceUtils.markScriptAsRendered(FacesContext, String, String)` tells me

> oamSubmit script is included inside jsf.js

here:

```
public static void markScriptAsRendered(FacesContext facesContext, String libraryName, String resourceName)
{
    getRenderedScriptResources(facesContext).put(
            libraryName != null ? libraryName+'/'+resourceName : resourceName, Boolean.TRUE);
    if (JAVAX_FACES_LIBRARY_NAME.equals(libraryName) &&
        JSF_JS_RESOURCE_NAME.equals(resourceName))
    {
        // If we are calling this method, it is expected myfaces core is being used as runtime and note
        // oamSubmit script is included inside jsf.js, so mark this one too.
        getRenderedScriptResources(facesContext).put(
                MYFACES_LIBRARY_NAME+'/'+MYFACES_JS_RESOURCE_NAME, Boolean.TRUE);
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm it is a bug. Solved in [MYFACES-4034](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-4034) for 2.2.10