# oamSubmit.js not included when f:ajax is present on a page

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, myfaces

I am running into a weird problem when using myfaces that is driving me nuts. I tried versions 2.2.10 and 2.2.12. I also use primefaces 6.0 but that might not be relevant.

Whenever I include an f:ajax tag on a page, commandLink no longer works and I get an error in the JavaScript console:

```
ReferenceError: myfaces is not defined
```

Digging deeper it turns out that the following line is no longer generated when there is a f:ajax tag on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/console/javax.faces.resource/oamSubmit.js.jsf?ln=org.apache.myfaces"></script>
```

When I manually add this script line everything works again! I do this by adding the folling javascript just after the  tag:

```
<script>
if (!window.myfaces) {
  document.write(unescape('%3Cscript type="text/javascript" src="/console/javax.faces.resource/oamSubmit.js.jsf?ln=org.apache.myfaces"%3E%3C/script%3E'));
}
</script>
```

Although everything seems to be working fine with this hack it gives me an uneasy feeling to have to do this. Can anyone shed a light on the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here. I stumbled upon [mojarra is not defined when javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE is Production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034312/mojarra-is-not-defined-when-javax-faces-project-stage-is-production)
and [submitForm() not defined for myfaces.JSF_JS_MODE 'minimal-modern'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34270601/submitform-not-defined-for-myfaces-jsf-js-mode-minimal-modern) and found out that the issue is only present in javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE=Production.

Adding

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.JSF_JS_MODE</param-name>
    <param-value>minimal</param-value>
</context-param>
```

to the web.xml fixed the issue for me.